# Stored procedure to find out if row exists before insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SS_InsertApplicationStatus] 
    @CustomerID int,
    @EventType nvarchar,
    @EventDateTime datetime,
    @Comments nvarchar,
    @EmployeeID varchar,
    @ApplicationDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXIST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SS_CustomerCard] 
                 WHERE SS_ID = '@SS_ID')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SS_ApplicationStatus (CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID, ApplicationDate)
        VALUES (@CustomerID, @EventType, @EventDateTime, @Comments, @EmployeeID, @ApplicationDate)
    END
END
```

There is an error on the line `IF NOT EXIST`; I copied this from MySQL.

What I want to do is

- IF no ROW exists, then I want to perform 2 inserts as shown here:

  ```
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO SS_ApplicationStatus (CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID, ApplicationDate)
    VALUES (@CustomerID, "Application Submission", @EventDateTime, @Comments, @EmployeeID, @ApplicationDate)

    INSERT INTO SS_ApplicationStatus (CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID, ApplicationDate)
    VALUES (@CustomerID, @EventType, @EventDateTime, @Comments, @EmployeeID, @ApplicationDate)
  ```
- if a ROW does exists

  ```
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO SS_ApplicationStatus (CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID, ApplicationDate)
    VALUES (@CustomerID, @EventType, @EventDateTime, @Comments, @EmployeeID, @ApplicationDate)
  ```

Comment: Instead of `SELECT count(*)`  just use `SELECT * FROM..`

Comment: @prograshid can you please post it as an answer and can you please be explicit? the IF NOT EXIST is giving an error in SQL Server.

Comment: can you post what error your are getting ? also check my answer.

Comment: **Bad habits to kick** : [Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Otherwise, you end up with parameter of a length of **exactly 1 character** - which I'm not sure is what you're really looking for ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use procedural logic? Make it fully set based. Of course you need to explain where `@SS_ID` comes from since it doesn't exist in your code snippet.

```
INSERT INTO SS_ApplicationStatus (CustomerID, EventType, EventDateTime, Comments, EmployeeID, ApplicationDate)
    SELECT @CustomerID, @EventType, @EventDateTime, @Comments, @EmployeeID, @ApplicationDate
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[SS_CustomerCard] WHERE SS_ID = @SS_ID);
```

Note in SQL Server:

- the keyword is `EXISTS` not `EXIST`
- you don't quote parameters, so it should be `@SS_ID` not `'@SS_ID'`

Answer (score 0):

There is logical error in following statement

```
IF NOT EXIST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SS_CustomerCard] WHERE SS_ID='@SS_ID')
```

You are using aggregate function `COUNT(*)` in your queries which will always return single row with a numeric value `1` or `0` based on your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: And quoting the parameter - which won't work.